# ImportError: No module named sekizai

Tags: django

I have installed all three dependencies according to the document 
(Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2 or higher.
Django 1.2.7 or higher.
django-classy-tags 0.3.1 or higher)
But when I add ‘sekizai’ into my INSTALLED_APPS setting, and execute "manage.py runserver", it will report "ImportError: No module named sekizai" to me.

My contents in settings.py:

```
    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'mptt',
        'hw',
        'useraccess',
        'proxy',
        'compressor',
        'sekizai',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'useraccess.middleware.VisitCollectMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    )

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'hw.context_processors.user_info',
    'hw.context_processors.login_form',
    'hw.context_processors.get_all_user',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)
```

Comment: Show us the relevant part of your `settings.py` file. And did you install `sekizai` or run `./manage.py startapp sekizai`?

Comment: Also, your error message in the title is not the same as the one you give in the last sentence. Which one is it?

Comment: Thus: did you install `sekizai` or create it? I don't see that anywhere mentioned. Nor your actual relevant settings.

Comment: I have updated my post. I installed the three dependencies mentioned in sekizai document. "Sudo pip install sekizai" didn't work and I didn't see other suggestions on how to install sekizai itself. So I thought it doesn't need to be installed before hand and can be used directly @Evert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-sekizai/django-sekizai-0.8.1.tar.gz
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

the answer updated 10 july 2021

```
pip install django
pip install django-cms
pip install django-sekizai

pip freeze

asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.5
django-classy-tags==2.0.0
django-cms==3.9.0
django-formtools==2.3
django-sekizai==2.0.0
django-treebeard==4.5.1
djangocms-admin-style==2.0.2
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
```